# Access helpers from Spree_frontend

Tags: ruby, helper, spree

I am writing an engine called `customize` that is used with `Spree_frontend`. What I am trying to do is to display the store pages using the store layout.

I have created a model `element`, its controller and its set of views in my engine, just the regular way:
in `@engine/app/controllers/customize/element_controller.rb`:

```
class Customize::ElementController < ApplicationController
  layout: Spree::Config.layout

  <my code>
end
```

When I run the application, I get an error because my engine `customize` does not find the helpers defined in `spree_frontend`. How should I declare these helpers inside my own engine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan Bigg kindly answered my question on Google Groups, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/JhsxcT648Cg. I quote his answer here:

> By using "include", you're including the methods from that specified
>   module into that controller. The methods from BaseHelper would
>   therefore be available only in the controller, and not as helper
>   methods in the view.
>
> I believe what you want to do is this:
>
> include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers  helper Spree::BaseHelper
>
> The helper method will make the methods from that module available in
>   the views for the controller where that line is.
>
> Ryan Bigg 
>   Community Manager 
>   Spree Commerce, Inc.

Many thanks, Ryan !!